# jquery ui - prevent draggable to be dropped on another  inside a droppable div

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Im looking for a way to prevent a draggable block to be dragged over another draggable block and vise versa. Or maybe how to detect it's being dragged over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/27/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent *dragging over* another, or *being dropped on* another?

Comment: Hi, yes u can drag it over a draggable but not being dropped on it! If it fail, it will be reverted to its last position.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated =)

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a simple demo which detects overlaps in your draggables.
Since their isn't native support to revert on a conditional in the drop event I created my own way of doing it. Here is a jsFiddle with the working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/37/

Comment: @Keith.Abramo After several drags and drops this solution gets confused and doesn't always work.  There is definitely a bug going on.  Sometimes the dragged element reverts back, sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes it gets stuck on top of another draggable element and then it keeps reverting back when you try to drag it back off.  The same with @pravin first solution too.  It just doesn't work.  The solution he posted in his comments works well, especially if you add `tolerance: 'touch'` to the droppable options.

Answer (score 0):

With revert option provided by jquery draggable you can revert position on invalid drops and overlap.

I have modified the answer given by Keith.Abramo.

Please not you need to use offset rather than position as during the overlap the position gets messed up.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/177/
Uses revert option

```
ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);
```

Another solution would be to make the draggable a droppable and use revert 'invalid' option on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/htWV3/1219/

HTML

```
<div class="drop">
  <div class="drag"></div>
  <div class="drag"></div>
  <div class="drag"></div>
  <div class="drag"></div>
  <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.drop').droppable({
  tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('.drag').draggable({
 revert: 'invalid',
 stop: function(){
     $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
 }
});

$('.drag').droppable({
 greedy: true,
 drop: function(event,ui){
    ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
 }
});
```

Disclaimer : I'm not sure who the author of the fiddle is.

Comment: Another good example is this(not sure who is the author tho)
Make the draggble a droppable and revert any item that is dropped on it.
http://jsfiddle.net/htWV3/1219/

Comment: Honestly your solution in the above comment should be the answer.  The above solutions that are posted as answers don't work very well.  They are really buggy and flawed.  You should re-post that as the answer.